# C# Deserialize recursive class

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, deserialization

I would like to have my data stored in an XML like this:

```
<MyType name="A">
  <MyType name="B" />
  <MyType name="E" />
  <MyType name="C">
    <MyType name="D">
    <MyType name="G">
  </MyType>
</MyType>
```

MyType should be a class that contains an array of other MyType instances. Is it possible to deserialize a class like this (with System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer) or do I have to load it with my own parser?

Also, is it possible to deserialize from an xml with custom header, ie. " instead of  ? TY for answers.

Comment: JSON.NET , nothing more to add.

Answer (score 3):

I think the xml isn't correct. D and G aren't closed.
With this xml,

```
<MyType name="A">
 <MyType name="B" />
 <MyType name="E" />
 <MyType name="C">
   <MyType name="D" />
   <MyType name="G" />          
 </MyType>
</MyType>
```

you can use this class to deserialize it :

```
[Serializable]
public class MyType
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="MyType")]
    public List<MyType> Types { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a really basic example you can take a look at this:

NOTE (the xml isnt quite like what you have described but you will need to fiddle with the xml attributes to get it doing exactly what you want, however structurally it represents the scenario you are asking for ie yes this is possible)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mytypeTest = new MyType
            {
                Name = "a",
                MyTypes = new List<MyType>
                {
                    new MyType
                    {
                        Name = "b"
                    }
                }.ToArray()
            };

            var xml = mytypeTest.Serialize();

            var result = xml.Deserialize<MyType>();
        }
    }

    public class MyType
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="MyType")]
        public MyType[] MyTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public static class XmlSerializerExtensions
    {
        public static T Deserialize<T>(this string xml) where T : new()
        {
            var _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var _stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                using (XmlReader _reader = new XmlTextReader(_stringReader))
                {
                    return (T)_serializer.Deserialize(_reader);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string Serialize<T>(this T value) where T : new()
        {
            var _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var _stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var _writer = new XmlTextWriter(_stream, new UTF8Encoding()))
                {
                    _serializer.Serialize(_writer, value);
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_stream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```